# how to toggle the same object for different object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

actually I really dont know how to express my problem.

you can see my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/astm1o3p/24/) so you will come to know about problem.

as you can see in fiddle when I am clicking on the first image the pop up appears but when I am clicking on the other image the popup hides ..I know it is the togggling effect but what to to if I want when I click on second image so the first toggle should over than other should start?

My Code

```
    <div id='player-back'>
    <img src='http://s6.postimg.org/su0e7812l/player1.png' data-playerid="1" id='p1'/>
    <img src='http://s6.postimg.org/afpv38orx/player2.png' data-playerid="2" id='p2'/>
    <img src='http://s6.postimg.org/h7ga63drh/player3.png' data-playerid="3" id='p3'/>
    <div id='player-popup' style="display:none">
            <span>Player1</span>
    </div>
    </div>

$("img").click(function(){
    var top = $(this).offset().top + $(this).width() + 2;
    var left = $(this).offset().left - $(this).height() / 2;  
    $("#player-popup span").text("Player "+$(this).data("playerid")); 
    $("#player-popup").css({ top: top, left: left }).toggle('slow');

});


#player-back{
    height:250px; 
    background:#0F0;
}
#p1{
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left:80px;
}
#p2{
    margin-left:150px;
}
#p3{
    margin-left:200px;
}
#player-popup{
    background:orange;
    height:27px;
    width:85px;
    border-radius:10px;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: is there any other way instead of playing with hide and show? that is my concern.

Comment: Your question has been answered correctly by multiple. You should bother to accept the suitable one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/astm1o3p/30/)

You need to hide your popup before toggle in case when you are clicking other object after one. So you can store previously clicked object in a variable like

```
var prevObj = null;
$("img").click(function(){    
    var top = $(this).offset().top + $(this).width() + 2;
    var left = $(this).offset().left - $(this).height() / 2;  
    $("#player-popup span").text("Player "+$(this).data("playerid")); 

    if(prevObj != this)
        $("#player-popup").hide();
    $("#player-popup").css({ top: top, left: left }).toggle('slow');    
    prevObj = this;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this:
https://jsfiddle.net/astm1o3p/28/

Use `hide()` with callback function (http://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide-duration-complete)

```
$("#player-popup").hide('slow', function() {
    if ($("#player-popup span").data("playerid") != $(that).data("playerid"))
    {
        $("#player-popup span").text("Player "+$(that).data("playerid")); 
        $("#player-popup span").data("playerid", $(that).data("playerid"));
        $("#player-popup").css({ top: top, left: left }).show('slow');
    }
});
```

It means that show will start when hide ends.

Comment: I edit the link, but when you look on code you see that at first it hide this popup whenever it is visible or not, then set position and show in this new position and with new text

Comment: I m talking about when you click on the player image it will show you a popup when you click it again it should hide but it gets hide but again shows

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Check edited code. just store extra data in your popup

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var playerId = '';
$("img").click(function(){
    var top = $(this).offset().top + $(this).width() + 2;
    var left = $(this).offset().left - $(this).height() / 2;  
    $("#player-popup span").text("Player "+$(this).data("playerid")); 
    if(playerId !=$(this).data("playerid") && $("#player-popup").css('display') != 'none'){
        $("#player-popup").css('display','none');
        playerId = $(this).data("playerid");
    }
    $("#player-popup").css({ top: top, left: left }).toggle('slow');

});
```

I have added a if condition, if there will be click on different player then it will hide other and will show current.

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d56gs3ph/).

Answer (score 0):

Simply hide your tooltip first on click.

```
$("img").click(function(){
    $("#player-popup").hide();
    var top = $(this).offset().top + $(this).width() + 2;
    var left = $(this).offset().left - $(this).height() / 2;  
    $("#player-popup span").text("Player "+$(this).data("playerid")); 
    $("#player-popup").css({ top: top, left: left }).toggle('slow');

});
```

Check this working **demo**
https://jsfiddle.net/astm1o3p/29/

Comment: in your demo the same thing is happening that when I am clicking on the image second time it gets hide and again pop up .

Comment: You wanted this effect as per my understanding. First tooltip should hide and then the next should be visible.

Comment: yeah but it should work like toggle i.e when I click on the image first time the pop up should appear and when I click on the same image the popup should disappear .that is not in your case .I hope you are getting my point